# Passing Data Between View Controllers DidSelectRowsAtIndexPath Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, didselectrowatindexpath

In a simple test app, i have tried to pass an array object named "thisArray" from the `MasterViewController` to the a string named "passedData" in the `DetailViewController`. I am using Storyboards and the `UIViewController` are embedded inside the navigation controller. Using the `prepareForSegue` method, i successfully passed the data between the `UIViewController`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushData"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.passedData = [thisArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Now for some reasons i want to use `didSelectRowsAtIndexPath` instead of `prepareForSegue`. I have used this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableString *object = thisArray[indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.passedData = object;   
}
```

But it didn't work. I have used the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSMutableString *object = thisArray[indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.passedData = object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];  
}
```

But it also didn't work.

**QUESTION**:

**1)** How to correctly write `didSelectRowsAtIndexPath` to replace `prepareForSegue`?

**2)** If i use `didSelectRowsAtIndexPath`, do i need to remove the segue connection between the `UIViewController` in the Storyboard?

**3)** What if there is really no segue connection between the view controllers, how can i still pass the data between them using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Based on the answer and the comments i received, i have wrote the following:

First i have removed the segue connection between the controllers, set the StoryBoard id `DetailViewController`, the name of the class is also `DetailViewController`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"DetailViewController"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];

    NSMutableString *object = thisArray[indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.passedData = object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**but its getting crashed with the following error:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: 'Could not find a storyboard
>   named `DetailViewController` in bundle

Comment: See dasblinkenlight's edit below, and change your updated code to his.  It should take care of what you are trying to do!  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second attempt is nearly right. The only thing that's not quite correct is the way you instantiate a view controller from a storyboard: you use `initWithNibNamed:`, which is what you use with NIBs but not with storyboards. For storyboards, you need this:

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"theStoryboardId"
                                          bundle:nil];
// If this code is inside a method called by a controller that is itself instantiated
// from a storyboard, you can replace the above line with this.storyboard
UIViewController* detailViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8848857/335858) for details.

Once you make the replacement, your code should work as expected.

**EDIT :**: Here is how your method would look:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController* detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
    NSMutableString *object = thisArray[indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.passedData = object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Clearly, that syntax is useful if going to another storyboard. But if the same storyboard, just use `self.storyboard`, e.g., `UIViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];`

Comment: should i just remove the segue connection between these view controller? and how can use "vc" to pass data ?

Comment: @AJ112 Yes, you need to remove the segue. The rest of your method does not change, starting with using `detailViewController.passedData = object;` to pass the data.

Comment: @rdelmar Of course I meant `self`, thanks! BTW, feel free to edit answers when you see obviously incorrect small stuff like that :) Thanks again!

Comment: +1, I changed the variable name "vc" to "detailViewController" in order for it to work with the rest of the method.

Comment: @gotnull This is not surprising, considering that the question pre-dates Swift by nearly a year. If you are looking for an answer with Swift, consider asking a separate question.